# Edit multiple elements in ObservableList and only fire change listeners after last change

Tags: java, javafx, observable

I have an ObservableList that doesn't only trigger the registered ListChangeListeners when elements are added or removed, but also when specific Observable attributes within these elements are changed, e.g. a list of persons and when a person's adress changes, the ListChangeListeners fire.
How can I edit the adress of multiple people and have the Listeners only fire once for all changes together?

Comment: That's not the way an `ObservableList` works, but have you tried to store copies of the elements intermediately in a different list, changing them there and doing `addAll` afterwards? Quite ugly, but might be sufficient...

Comment: The class `ListChangeListener.Change` provides an option to check for updated elements (see `wasUpdated()`). In that case, `getFrom()` and `getTo()` will specificy the interval of updated elements. So you say, there is no implementation of ObservableList that supports multiple updates despite the fact, that these changes are supported by the ListChangeListener framework?

Comment: yes, sure - not everything that can be supported actually is supported (took years to get even a basic support for notification of property changes to individual items) Either live with it or roll your own, it's not that hard: have a look at the implementation of ObservableListBase and its subs. Forgot: there are libraries out in the wild that support delayed/summary notification, f.i. reactfx (don't know its current state, though)

Comment: remove all registered listeners, perform the bulk changes, add the registered listeners just after the last silent change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObservableList` does not provide this functionality by default. If you extend [`ModifiableObservableList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html) though, you could make it's `beginChange()` and `endChange()` functionality accessible to external code.

You need to be careful though that this class is used correctly. If you do not do the same number of `beginChange` and `endChange` calls, the listener may not receive any updates at all.

The following code does not contain any implementation regarding update changes. I'll leave this up to you. You'll need to use `nextUpdate` between calls of `beginChange` and `endChange`. You may need to add additional functionality to the `doXyz` methods to add listeners, if you want that the extractor functionality.

```
public class BulkEditObservableList<T> extends ModifiableObservableListBase<T> {

    private final List<T> backingList;

    public BulkEditObservableList(List<T> backingList) {
        if (backingList == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.backingList = backingList;
    }

    public BulkEditObservableList() {
        this(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return backingList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return backingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, T element) {
        backingList.add(index, element);

    }

    @Override
    protected T doSet(int index, T element) {
        return backingList.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected T doRemove(int index) {
        return backingList.remove(index);
    }

    public void beginBulkChange() {
        beginChange();
    }

    public void endBulkChange() {
        endChange();
    }

}
```

Usage example

```
BulkEditObservableList<Integer> intList = new BulkEditObservableList<>();
intList.addListener((Observable o) -> System.out.println(o));
intList.add(1);

intList.beginBulkChange();
intList.add(2);
intList.add(3);
intList.add(0, 0);
System.out.println("after multi add");
intList.endBulkChange();
```

Output

```
[1]
after multi add
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```