# Is there any way to clear ObservableList without calling the onChanged method?

Tags: android, javafx

I have the following situation:

[image]

I have activity and several fragments. At the beginning of the onCreate method I always load the fragment present in the picture above:

```
 private void setInitialFragment() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DietDiaryFragment dietDiaryFragment = (DietDiaryFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("DietDiaryFragment");

    if (dietDiaryFragment == null) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        dietDiaryFragment = new DietDiaryFragment();
        setArguments(dietDiaryFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main_screen, dietDiaryFragment,"DietDiaryFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Where the setArguments method is as follows:

```
private void setArguments(DietDiaryFragment dietDiaryFragment) {

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putParcelable("breakfast", breakfast);
bundle.putParcelable("lunch", lunch);
bundle.putParcelable("dinner", dinner);
bundle.putParcelable("snacks", snacks);

dietDiaryFragment.setArguments(bundle);

}
```

In activity, I download from Firebase all products from a given meal, depending on the date and send it to the fragment where I showed above:

```
private void getProductsFromDatabaseLunch() {

    lunch.getTotalProducts().clear();
    lunch.getIdProducts().clear();
    lunch.setTotalCalories(0);

    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(currentUserUID)
            .collection("Types of Meals").document("Lunch")
            .collection("Date of Lunch").document(date)
            .collection("List of Products")
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: task.getResult().getDocuments()) {

                    lunch.getIdProducts().add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                    lunch.getTotalProducts().add(documentSnapshot.toObject(Product.class));
                }

                lunch.calculateTotalCalories();
                onSendTotalCaloriesLunch.sendTotalCaloriesLunch(lunch.getTotalCalories());
            }

            if(getFragmentRefreshLunchAdapter() != null) {

                getFragmentRefreshLunchAdapter().refreshLunchAdapter();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Downloading products from Firebase is asynchronous, so first empty ArrayLists without products will be passed, only after a while products are added.

To perform some calculations and display the results obtained, I used ObservableList, which informs me that the products have been downloaded from Firebase.

```
observableProductListSnacks.addAll(snacks.getTotalProductsOfMeal());
```

Method onChanged:

```
observableProductListBreakfast.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Product>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Product> change) {

            Log.i("Calories 1", String.valueOf(breakfast.getTotalCaloriesOfMeal()));

            breakfast.calculateTotalCarbohydratesOfMeal();
            breakfast.calculateTotalProteinOfMeal();
            breakfast.calculateTotalFatOfMeal();
            breakfast.calculateTotalCaloriesOfMeal();

            Log.i("Calories 2", String.valueOf(breakfast.getTotalCaloriesOfMeal()));

            if(breakfast.getTotalProductsOfMeal().size() == 0) {

                textViewTotalCaloriesBreakfast.setText("");

            } else {

                textViewTotalCaloriesBreakfast.setText(product.formatNumberWithoutDecimalPlaces(breakfast.getTotalCaloriesOfMeal()));
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that when I extend the calendar and navigate between days, products will constantly be added to observableProductListSnacks. Therefore, after changing the day I try to clear observableProductListSnacks, but ... then the onUpdate method is executed twice. Is there any way to avoid this? Or is it not a problem that the products build up on different days in observableProductListSnacks? Or it is not a problem that the onUpdate method is executed twice, because i clear observableProductListSnacks and then download products from new day ?

Comment: See fabian's answer to: [Edit multiple elements in ObservableList and only fire change listeners after last change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324227/edit-multiple-elements-in-observablelist-and-only-fire-change-listeners-after-la/59326382#59326382)

Comment: In this case I'd rather recommend using `setAll` to add the new items (assuming there is only one update for the list running) or possibly store the info whether someone should overwrite the contents or append them in a field (or equivalent) and possibly create a object hiding this functionality from the producer depending on how much effort you're trying to spend on keeping that logic seperate from the logic acting depending on the changes...